# Is it possible that my UV LED is emitting white light? If so, how would I filter out the white light?

Tags: led, filter, optics, uv

I recently purchased a 365 nm UV LED, and set up the proper circuit.  When I turn the power on, the LED lights up very dimly.  Is this white light (that's the color I saw) being emitted from the LED? If so, are there any methods (preferably inexpensive) for blocking out only visible light?

The specs for the UV LED can be found here:
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/228/LZ1-00UV00-257812.pdf

Comment: ... How are you observing this, your eyes may perceive some UV, it will appear with a strange purple tint in some cases that may appear whitish. It is **not** a good idea to look at it directly, even when diffuse but especially if its narrow angle. The datasheet shows a relatively narrow band that does not bleed significantly into visible. If the spectrum is appropriate for you I wouldn't worry about it

Comment: I was looking it from an angle wearing UV-protective glasses. Is that okay safety-wise?  It was for no more than a second.

Comment: Most glass will block UV adequately, but the color you observe may be due to a variety of reasons. Ideally you could characterize a spectrum, a crude way to do this is to use a prism and see if you can see some visible lines on dark paper. You can compare with a white LED to get a rough estimate of how likely it is that you have visible frequency modes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figure 5 of the linked datasheet shows there is a small amount of emission in the >380 nm range.

I [digitized](http://arohatgi.info/WebPlotDigitizer/app/) the spectrum and computed how much relative radiant flux there is greater than 380 nm.

\begin{gather}
\Phi_\text{visible} = \frac{\int_\text{380 nm}^{\infty} \Phi_{\lambda} \text{d} \lambda}{\int_{0}^{\infty} \Phi_{\lambda} \text{d} \lambda} \approx 0.087
\end{gather}

So a bit under 10 % of the radiant flux is being emitted in the visible spectrum. I don't know what color this would look like in practice, though I suspect it might be have blue-violet hue since about 88 % of this is in the 380–400 nm range. Assuming 1050 mW total radiant flux, this means there's about 92 mW emitted in the visible spectrum.

You can find "reasonably priced" (~30 USD) shortpass and bandpass filters which transmit UV while blocking visible wavelengths, for example [this one](http://www.edmundoptics.com/optics/optical-filters/bandpass-filters/colored-glass-bandpass-filters/46081/). This would reduce the visible radiant flux to about 10–30 mW (eyeball estimated). If you have more money available, there are of course [better filters](http://www.edmundoptics.com/optics/optical-filters/bandpass-filters/fluorescence-bandpass-filters/84109/).